# Image of Veronese Map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $S_dV^{\star}$ denotes the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ on a vector space $V$, and the Veronese map $v_d:V^{*} \rightarrow S_dV^{\star}$, takes $\psi \mapsto \psi^d$, where $\psi \in V^{*}$. Then I have to prove that over a field of zero characteristic, $\langle\text{Im}(v_d)\rangle=S_dV^{\star}$ i.e. the image of $v_d$ spans the whole $S_dV^{*}$.

Now, I know the following: $\dim S_dV^{\star} = {{n+d-1}\choose{d}}$, when $\dim V=n$. And the basis of $S_dV^{\star}$ are the set of monomials $x_1^{m_1}\cdot x_2^{m_2} \cdot \dotsc \cdot x_n^{m_n}$, such that $\sum m_i=d$. Then how do I show that the image of map spans the entire $S_dV^{\star}$?

My attempt: It's clear that $\text{span}(\text{Im}(v_d)) \subseteq S_dV^{\star}$. Now, for any $f \in S_dV^{\star}$, I was just able to verify using examples, which I know doesn't show anything. Example I used: $x^2 + xy + y^2=(x/2+y)^2 + (3/4)x^2$, where $x,y \in V^{*}$, $V = \mathbb{k^2}$ and $d=2$

Comment: Try using that $\nu_dx_1 \lambda x_2)$ lies in the image for all values of $\lambda \in k$, where $k$ is the field and has infinetly many elements. Then maybe try using the same procedure in a bit more generality.